# React Native Expandable List View

Tags: react-native, expandablelistview

How can I create an expandable list view in react native? I want to give a functionality in which when I press the button it displays an expandable list view.
Please have a look for a proper example in this link https://cdn.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/android-expandablelistview-example.gif

Comment: take a look at the follwing npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ercpereda/react-native-accordion
i think this is what you want

Comment: you're welcome hope this helps